# Getting value as undefined for input textboxes that are in a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with multiple rows that contain textboxes. I just want to get the value of the textboxes and add them together.

I've tried using `innerHTML`, but I get the whole entire input box html. If I use `value` I get undefined.

Javascript:

```js
    function getTotal()
            {
                var amt;
                var subTotal = 0;
                var FTA = document.getElementById("cphMain_gridFTA");

                for(i=1; i < FTA.rows.length ; i++)
                {

                    amt = FTA.rows[i].cells[1].value;
                    alert(amt)
                    if(isNaN(amt))
                    {
                        subTotal += 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subTotal += parseFloat(amt);
                    }


                }

            }
```

HTML:

```html
    <table id="cphMain_gridFTA">
      <tbody>
        <tr>...<tr> 
        <tr>
          <td>
          ...
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="1" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_0" onblur="getTotal()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          ...
          </td>
          <td>  
            <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="2" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_1" onblur="getTotal()">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I would like to get the `value` of each row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to precise the childnode you want to access.

Try replacing this line :

```
amt = FTA.rows[i].cells[1].value;
```

With this one :

```
amt = FTA.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the `input` tags, then change your

`document.getElementById("cphMain_gridFTA")` to 
`document.getElementsByTagName("input")`

This will get the `td` tags which holds your `input` tags so you can retrieve the values. In your for loop, you must change `i=1` to `i=0` to start on the first index of 0 so your for loop can loop correctly. Within you for loop, just get the `value` of each item it loops through and add that to your `subTotal`. Then I just added an alert to alert the user of the total of the `input` boxes. Hopefully this helps get you in the right direction.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kyn278rq/

Comment: That seems to only get the first rows cell data.

Comment: You only have one row with an input tag in your html code.

Comment: Oh, what about multiple rows?

Comment: Can you update your html code to include multiple rows? I don't have  a problem on working on getting that for you but the initial code threw me off because you only have one text-box in your code.

Comment: No problem, I added more. I actually only need the "value"

Comment: ok, what do you want to do with the value? Have the sum of them values in the alert call? or just alert what each value is on the blur call?

Comment: I just need to sum the values. I was just using the alert call to check if the values were coming through.

Comment: ok, I will see what I can do

Comment: @Juan I've edited my answer

Comment: Looks like it works in the jsfiddle, but not in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201852/discussion-between-king11-and-juan).